# Intern AuditSystem in DB and getting users from it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My project has a change on the database, so that every INSERT-UPDATE-DELETE action is logged with triggers on the DB.

For that they have an extra table created:

Table `T_USER` is new and have a PK, a discriminator field and some other fields, Table `T_APP_USER` contains an PK witch is also FK to PK of `T_USER`.

In some Pojo's I need to show the last_changed_user, this should be normally comes from `T_APP_USER` but if a manuel intervention on the DB is done this could be an `T_USER` who is not known in `T_APP_USER`.

The following code works, but I'm interested in review, possibilities for other solution (user may be empty when it's a internal DB user).  For the moment I add the `AuditUser` in the Pojo cause all the methods of `User` has been abstracted I can still get to all details of a User.

Abstract user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
public abstract class AuditUser extends PersistentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "T_USER_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "T_USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "T_USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "user_sid", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private char status = 'A';

    /**
     * getter for id.
     *
     * @return the id of the user.
     */
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * getter for status. A => Application user. D => Internal DB user.
     *
     * @return the status of the user
     */
    public char getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * setter of the status(discriminator) A => Application user. D => Internal
     * DB user.
     *
     * @param status the Status to set.
     */
    public void setStatus(char status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     * getter for account.
     *
     * @return the account of the user
     */
    public abstract String getAccount();

    /**
     * getter for "active status".
     *
     * @return the "active status" of the user
     */
    public abstract Boolean getActive();

    /**
     * Gets the army number.
     *
     * @return the army number
     */
    public abstract String getArmyNumber();

    /**
     * getter for email.
     *
     * @return the email of the user
     */
    public abstract String getEmail();

    /**
     * getter for firstName.
     *
     * @return the firstName of the user
     */
    public abstract String getFirstName();

    /**
     * getter for knowing if user comes from LDAP or not.
     *
     * @return true when user comes from LDAP, false when not
     */
    public abstract Boolean getIsLdapAccount();

    /**
     * Gets the last login.
     *
     * @return the last login
     */
    public abstract Date getLastLogin();

    /**
     * getter for lastName.
     *
     * @return the lastName of the user
     */
    public abstract String getLastName();

    /**
     * getter for office.
     *
     * @return the office of the user
     */
    public abstract String getOffice();

    /**
     * getter for password.
     *
     * @return the password of the user
     */
    public abstract String getPassword();

    /**
     * getter for phone number.
     *
     * @return the phone number of the user
     */
    public abstract String getPhone();

    /**
     * Gets the private email.
     *
     * @return the private email
     */
    public abstract String getPrivateEmail();

    /**
     * getter for Set of roles.
     *
     * @return the Set of roles of the user
     */
    public abstract Set<Role> getRoles();

    /**
     * getter for the rank.
     *
     * @return the rank of the user
     */
    public abstract String getTitle();

    /**
     * getter for the fullName.
     *
     * @return the fullname of the user.
     */
    public abstract String getFullName();

    /**
     * getter for unit.
     *
     * @return the unit of the user
     */
    public abstract String getUnit();

    /**
     * Getter for the userName.
     *
     * @return the username of the user.
     */
    public abstract String getUsername();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User with account : " + this.getAccount()
                + "\n and lastname : " + this.getLastName()
                + "\n and firstname : " + this.getFirstName()
                + "\n and email : " + this.getEmail()
                + "\n and password : " + this.getPassword()
                + "\n and private email : " + this.getPrivateEmail();
    }
}
```

The implementation of the normal application user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_APP_USER", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"account"})})
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "USER_SID", referencedColumnName = "USER_SID")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
@Cacheable(value = false)
public class User extends AuditUser implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * The Constant serialVersionUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8728575886998109132L;
    private static final int MAX_LENGHT_ACCOUNT = 30;
    private static final int MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT = 50;
    private static final int PRIME = 31;
    /**
     * The account.
     */
    @Column(name = "account", nullable = true, unique = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_ACCOUNT)
    private String account;
    /**
     * The active.
     */
    @Column(name = "is_Active", nullable = true)
    private Boolean active = Boolean.TRUE; // Must be "true", otherwise you'll get "User is disabled" at login.
    /**
     * The email.
     */
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String email;
    /**
     * The first name.
     */
    @Column(name = "first_Name", nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String firstName;
    /**
     * The last name.
     */
    @Column(name = "last_Name", nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String lastName;
    /**
     * The is ldap account.
     */
    @Column(name = "is_Ldap_Account", nullable = true)
    private Boolean isLdapAccount = false;
    /**
     * The office.
     */
    @Column(name = "office", nullable = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String office;
    /**
     * The password.
     */
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true)
    private String password;
    /**
     * The phone.
     */
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String phone;
    /**
     * The roles.
     */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Role.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_USER_ROLE", joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_sid", referencedColumnName = "user_sid"), inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_sid", referencedColumnName = "role_sid"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    /**
     * The title.
     */
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String title;
    /**
     * The unit.
     */
    @Column(name = "unit", nullable = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String unit;
    /**
     * The private email.
     */
    @Column(name = "PRIVATE_EMAIL", nullable = true, length = MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT)
    private String privateEmail;
    /**
     * The army number.
     */
    @Column(name = "MATRICULE")
    private String armyNumber;
    /**
     * The last login.
     */
    @Column(name = "LAST_LOGIN_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastLogin;

    /**
     * constructor for class.
     */
    public User() {
        this.roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new user.
     *
     * @param user the user
     */
    public User(final org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user) {
        this.account = user.getUsername();
        this.roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        for (final GrantedAuthority gr : user.getAuthorities()) {
            this.roles.add(new Role(gr.getAuthority()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a role to a user.
     *
     * @param role the role
     * @return true if OK, false if not OK.
     */
    public boolean addRole(final Role role) {
        return this.roles.add(role);
    }

    /**
     * CompareTo written on account with an ignore case comparator.
     *
     * @param persistentEntity the entity to compare to
     * @return the integer outcome
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final PersistentEntity persistentEntity) {
        if (this.equals(persistentEntity)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (persistentEntity == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != persistentEntity.getClass()) {
            return -1;
        }
        final User other = (User) persistentEntity;
        return StringComparator.IGNORE_CASE_STRING_AND_TRIM_COMPARATOR.compare(
                this.getAccount(), other.getAccount());
    }

    /**
     * Equals written on account -ignoring the case and trimming-.
     *
     * @param obj the object to compare with
     * @return the boolean outcome
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final User other = (User) obj;
        if (this.account == null) {
            if (other.account != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.account.equals(other.account)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * getter for account.
     *
     * @return the account of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }

    /**
     * getter for "active status".
     *
     * @return the "active status" of the user
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the army number.
     *
     * @return the army number
     */
    @Override
    public String getArmyNumber() {
        return this.armyNumber;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getAuthorities()
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        final Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles2 = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (final Role role : this.getRoles()) {
            roles2.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority()));
        }
        return roles2;
    }

    /**
     * getter for email.
     *
     * @return the email of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    /**
     * getter for firstName.
     *
     * @return the firstName of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    /**
     * getter for id.
     *
     * @return the id of the user
     */
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    /**
     * getter for knowing if user comes from LDAP or not.
     *
     * @return true when user comes from LDAP, false when not
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean getIsLdapAccount() {
        return this.isLdapAccount;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the last login.
     *
     * @return the last login
     */
    @Override
    public Date getLastLogin() {
        return this.lastLogin;
    }

    /**
     * getter for lastName.
     *
     * @return the lastName of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    /**
     * getter for office.
     *
     * @return the office of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getOffice() {
        return this.office;
    }

    /**
     * getter for password.
     *
     * @return the password of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    /**
     * getter for phone number.
     *
     * @return the phone number of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the private email.
     *
     * @return the private email
     */
    @Override
    public String getPrivateEmail() {
        return this.privateEmail;
    }

    /**
     * getter for Set of roles.
     *
     * @return the Set of roles of the user
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return this.roles;
    }

    /**
     * getter for the rank.
     *
     * @return the rank of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFullName() {
        return getLastName() + " " + getFirstName();
    }

    /**
     * getter for unit.
     *
     * @return the unit of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getUnit() {
        return this.unit;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getUsername()
     */
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.getAccount();
    }

    /**
     * HashCode written on account -ignoring the case and trimming-.
     *
     * @return the integer outcome
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int result = PRIME
                + ((this.account == null) ? 0 : this.account.toLowerCase().trim()
                .hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonExpired()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonLocked()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isCredentialsNonExpired()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isEnabled()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }

    /**
     * Before persisting, the account of the user is put in lowercase and
     * trimmed.
     */
    @PrePersist
    void prePersist() {
        if (this.account != null) {
            this.account = this.account.toLowerCase().trim();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unable to persist a null-value for user.account");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove a role from a user.
     *
     * @param role the role
     * @return true if OK, false if not OK.
     */
    public boolean removeRole(final Role role) {
        return this.roles.remove(role);
    }

    /**
     * setter for account of the user.
     *
     * @param account of the user
     */
    public void setAccount(final String account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    /**
     * setter for active status of the user.
     *
     * @param active status of the user
     */
    public void setActive(final Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the army number.
     *
     * @param armyNumber the new army number
     */
    public void setArmyNumber(final String armyNumber) {
        this.armyNumber = armyNumber;
    }

    /**
     * setter for email of the user.
     *
     * @param email of the user
     */
    public void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * setter for firstName of the user.
     *
     * @param firstName of the user
     */
    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * setting true when user comes from LDAP, false when not.
     *
     * @param isLdapAccount boolean value to tell when user comes from LDAP or
     * not
     */
    public void setIsLdapAccount(final Boolean isLdapAccount) {
        this.isLdapAccount = isLdapAccount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the last login.
     */
    public void setLastLogin() {
        this.lastLogin = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    /**
     * setter for lastName of the user.
     *
     * @param lastName of the user
     */
    public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * setter for office of the user.
     *
     * @param office of the user
     */
    public void setOffice(final String office) {
        this.office = office;
    }

    /**
     * setter for password of the user.
     *
     * @param password of the user
     */
    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * setter for phone of the user.
     *
     * @param phone of the user
     */
    public void setPhone(final String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the private email.
     *
     * @param privateEmail the new private email
     */
    public void setPrivateEmail(final String privateEmail) {
        this.privateEmail = privateEmail;
    }

    /**
     * setter for Set of roles of the user.
     *
     * @param roles the new roles
     */
    public void setRoles(final Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    /**
     * setter for the rank of the user.
     *
     * @param title the new title
     */
    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * setter for unit of the user.
     *
     * @param unit of the user
     */
    public void setUnit(final String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Implementation of the `DbUser`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DB_USER")
@DiscriminatorValue("D")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "USER_SID", referencedColumnName = "USER_SID")
public class DbUser extends AuditUser {

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String name;

    /**
     * getter for the name
     *
     * @return the name of the database user.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * setter for the name
     *
     * @param name the name to set for the database user.
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * getter for account.
     *
     * @return the account of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getAccount() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * getter for "active status".
     *
     * @return the "active status" of the user
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean getActive() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the army number.
     *
     * @return the army number
     */
    @Override
    public String getArmyNumber() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for email.
     *
     * @return the email of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getEmail() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for firstName.
     *
     * @return the firstName of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for knowing if user comes from LDAP or not.
     *
     * @return true when user comes from LDAP, false when not
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean getIsLdapAccount() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the last login.
     *
     * @return the last login
     */
    @Override
    public Date getLastLogin() {
        return new Date();
    }

    /**
     * getter for lastName.
     *
     * @return the lastName of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return "Internal DB user";
    }

    /**
     * getter for office.
     *
     * @return the office of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getOffice() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for password.
     *
     * @return the password of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for phone number.
     *
     * @return the phone number of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getPhone() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Gets the private email.
     *
     * @return the private email
     */
    @Override
    public String getPrivateEmail() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for Set of roles.
     *
     * @return the Set of roles of the user
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    /**
     * getter for the rank.
     *
     * @return the rank of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * getter for the fullName.
     *
     * @return the fullname of the user.
     */
    @Override
    public String getFullName() {
        return getLastName();
    }

    /**
     * getter for unit.
     *
     * @return the unit of the user
     */
    @Override
    public String getUnit() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the userName.
     *
     * @return the username of the user.
     */
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return getLastName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks good. I've visited this question multiple times and I couldn't find anything. Design-wise there might be improvements, but the implementation looks very good. The only thing I found was this.

```
/**
 * Equals written on account -ignoring the case and trimming-.
 *
 * @param obj the object to compare with
 * @return the boolean outcome
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final User other = (User) obj;
    if (this.account == null) {
        if (other.account != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!this.account.equals(other.account)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This last bit:

```
    if (this.account == null) {
        if (other.account != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!this.account.equals(other.account)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Could be this instead:

```
    if (this.account == null) {
        return other.account == null;
    } else {
        return this.account.equals(other.account);
    }
```

It simplifies things.

---

Additionally, I'd take a look at your comments, not all of them make sense...

```
/**
 * The is ldap account.
 */
@Column(name = "is_Ldap_Account", nullable = true)
private Boolean isLdapAccount = false;
```

And you seem to have misspelled your constants.

```
private static final int MAX_LENGHT_ACCOUNT = 30;
private static final int MAX_LENGHT_DEFAULT = 50;
```

(LENGHT -> LENGTH)